# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' error

Tags: python

I am trying to add the contents of the score file together and get an average but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```py
# open and read file student / score
student_file = open("Student.txt", "r")
score_file = open("Score.txt", "r")
student = student_file.read().split(' ')
score = score_file.read().split(' ')
addedScore = 0.0
average = 0.0

for i in range(0,len(student)):

    print("Student: "+student[i]+" Final: "+score[i])          
    addedScore = addedScore + score[i]

average = addedScore / 2
print("The class average is:", average)
```

The score file is full of float numbers:

```
90.0 94.0 74.4 63.2 79.4 87.6 67.7 78.1 95.8 82.1
```

The error message

```
line 12, in <module>
addedScore = addedScore + score[i]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: `addedScore = addedScore + float(score[i])`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `score` was created by splitting a string, it's elements are all strings; hence the complaint about trying to add a float to a string.  If you want the value that that string represents, you need to compute that; something like `float(score[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

`score` is a list of strings, so you definitely cannot add a string to a float as you do here: `addedScore = addedScore + score[i]`. You have to convert this string to a float: `addedScore = addedScore + float(score[i])`

Answer (score 2):

When you split the contents of the file, they are still strings.  Change `score = score_file.read().split(' ')` to `score = [float(x) for x in score_file.read().split(" ")]`.  You probably don't need to do `.split(" ")`, because `str.split()` will by default split by whitespace.  Therefore, you can use `.split()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just add str type to the `print("The class average is:", average)`.

Solution:

`print("The class average is:", str(average))`

it will come up with the same result you just convert it to string. so the value will now combined string to string as for the error of unsupported operand type.